# How to pass CSS modules in props?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I'm getting `h2` undefined in `component2`.
How to pass CSS module in props? Adding `className` to a child component from the parent component through props.

Using: Next.js version 11.1.0

example:

component1:

```
import React from 'react'
import Component2 from './Component2'
import styles from './css/styles.module.css'

function component1() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className={styles.h1}>hello World</h1>
            <Component2 styles={styles}/>
       </>
    )
}

export default component1
```

component2:

```
import React from 'react'

function component2(props) {

    const styles = props.styles

    return (
        <>
            <h2 className={styles.h2}>Hellow World 2</h2>
        </>
    )
}

export default component2
```

Comment: Please show your css module file

Comment: Rather than passing `styles`, have you tried passing down `styles.h2` down to `Component2` instead?

Comment: Thats not a way, you are loading a css file.. You shuld do import './App.css';

Comment: Or   render() {
    const mystyle = {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
      padding: "10px",
      fontFamily: "Arial"
    };
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

Comment: Not reproducible: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-chihiro-h1l34

Comment: @StefanAvramovic That's not how things work with Next.js. One cannot import global CSS files (except from `_app.js`). And what OP has done is a correct way to use CSS modules.

Comment: @juliomalves i just tried that. while this method removed the compiling error, the classname is being set to  'undefiend'. `<div className='undefined'></div>`

Comment: @brc-dd wired it works fine in this code sand box. but not in my app

Comment: add this import './App.css';  in the component2 file and, in your App.css you have a class like for example .heading{color:red;}  then the  class name shuld be className='heading'

Comment: So the prop is undefined becous jou are passing an empty prop to the second component